# Android- How to update data on another activity. Outside the one you're working on

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've got a simple android app that organises a list of items. I'm still a beginner so forgive any ambiguity in the question.

The main activity consists of a list of existing items & two buttons, add item, and retrieve items. Retrieving item pulls all current items from an SQLite database and displays them.

When I add an item, it works fine and adds a new item to the database and when I close the activity that handles adding an item, the new item doesn't appear automatically, I have to retrieve the data again. 
I want to be able to see a new item on the screen as soon as I close the add item activity.
The code for retrieving items in a database in the main activity is:

```
MovieDBAdapter dbadapter = new MovieDBAdapter(this);
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> movieList =  dbadapter.getMovieList();
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, movieList, R.layout.view_movie_entry, new String[] {"id", "title"}, new int[] {R.id.movie_Id, R.id.title});
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I tried adding this code in the other activity but it threw an error because the setListAdapter method only applies to classes which extend listActivity and the class which adds a new item doesn't.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be great.

Summary: I want to update activity straight away without having to call a separate method in the mainActivity class.

Comment: You may use `CursorLoader` to load it from database. whenever you update database `CursorLoader` will update everything automatically. is that your question? docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html

Comment: You can use `BaseAdapter` and each time that `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` is called, it reloads the items. You can call it in `onResume` method. The activity that has the list is which has to have the adapter. What you want to do has no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call addItem Activity using

```
 startActivityForResult(Intent intent,  int requestCode);
```

once the item in added call

```
 setResult(resultCode)
```

So then implement the following in Other activity

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
  Intent data) {
// Check which request we're responding to
// here update the list
}
```

So setReult calls OnActivityResult once the item is added.